# What's after the adhaan in this video of it from Al Aqsa masjid

Tags: adhan

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbmcjErkTUM
The link is of the adhaan from Masjid Al Aqsa and ends at 4:03 but at 4:12 other words are said - what are these and these aren't part of the adhaan are they?

Answer (score 3):

No, they aren't part of the Adhan. It is just sending blessings upon the Prophet after the Adhan.

He says:

"*Allahumma salli wa sallim wa barik*" (O Allah bestow Your grace and peace and blessings)

"*ala sayyidina Muhammad wa ‘ala alehi*" (upon our leader Muhammad and on his family)

"*wa sahaabahi ajama'in*" (and the Companions, all of them).

Absolutely beautifully recited.